# Windows Azure VPN public access

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, vpn, public

I created a VM in a VPN in Windows Azure. I added TCP endpoints for the particular machine which runs server 2012. But everytime I run a small program listening on TCP like the example in [nodejs](http://nodejs.org), any client simply refuses to connect. This happens even when I disable the firewall? I tried with linux (ubuntu) too. Can someone help me out and let me know what steps I am missing? I connected with:
server1.cloudapp.net:tcp_port

RDP and SSH work fine through TCP.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to check, which may provide more clue. 
1) double check your endpoint, make sure the public port and private port are set correctly
2) rdp to the VM and do "netstat -an" to check if the port is indeed listening